# Different sort rules based on a conditional using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

For a project I'm working on, I have a dataset containing fruits that with the columns Name, Colour, Country, Order_ID.

I sort it in order of Name (ascending), Colour (ascending), Country (ascending), Order_ID (ascending). To do this I use:

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['Name', 'Colour', 'Country', 'Order_ID'], ascending=[True, True, True, True])
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

However, I would like to implement a rule that sorts the `Country` and `Order_ID` of all Bananas in a descending manner. This would look like this:

[image]

Is there any elegant way to achieve this using pandas? I played with the group-by function but wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: pull out the `Banana` records and sort descending and concat back

Comment: @anky_91 will the sorted records be placed back in the right position once I concat them?

Comment: Umm no I think ,can you provide the dataframe as text, so we can test though? Thank you.